# PHP ob_end_clean does not clear buffer

Tags: php

What I'm trying to do is to response with a JSON array of output of PHP files.

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$ret["response"] = array();

$items = getItems();
$ret["response"] = array();
ob_start();
foreach($items as $model){
    include("view/item.php");
    $ret["response"][] = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
}
ob_end_clean();
echo json_encode($ret);
```

the file `view/item.php` contains some PHP `echo` statements, but the problem is that response contains the output of `include` statement and the JSON encoded items.

how do i make the script return only  the JSON part?

Comment: What happens if you add `ob_start()` also in your `foreach`?

Answer (score 1):

Try your code like,

```
foreach($items as $model){
    ob_start();
    include("view/item.php");
    $ret["response"][] = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
}
ob_end_clean();
```

or,

```
ob_start();
foreach($items as $model){
    include("view/item.php");
    $ret["response"][] = ob_get_contents();
}
ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

Second option will work fine.

```
ob_start();
foreach($items as $model){
  include("view/item.php");
  $ret["response"][] = ob_get_contents();
}
ob_end_clean();
```